# Regional targeting on continent level, same language, 2 domains

Tags: redirects, duplicate-content, hreflang, geotargeting, canonical-url

I have a question concerning regional targeting of a website. I have 2 websites with exactly the same content and both in English (exact copy), but different domains:

- `abc.example`
- `xwz.example`

I would like to redirect visitors from Europe to `abc.example` and the rest of the visiters to `xwz.example`.

My approach is to do so by IP detection. Showing a pop up to the user and informing them that they are being redirected to a suitable version for x y reasons.

But the real problem is: What should be the perfect approach to letting the search engines (Google) know that these are 2 versions of the same website and avoid penalties for duplicate content or other penalties?

The `rel="alternate" hreflang=""` solution would be the best solution if it was on a coutry level, but we want to target whole European countries on one site and the rest of the world on the otherside.

Should we use a `canonical` tag? How can we tell Google that this version is for Europeans and this other version is for the rest of the world?

Answer (score 1):

The [IANA Language Subtag Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry) does define relevant region subtags:

- `150` for Europe
- `EU` for the [European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union)
- `EZ` for the [Eurozone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurozone)

So you could use this `link` element to link from `xwz.example` to `abc.example`:

```html
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-150" href="https://abc.example/" />
```

For the link in the other direction, you can only use a tag without a region (because there is no way to convey "everything except this region"):

```html
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://xwz.example/" />
```

If the pages are really identical (e.g., no comment system, which would lead to different comments on otherwise identical pages), you should use `canonical` in addition. `xwz.example` should probably be the canonical one.